# google.script.run times varies a lot

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, server-side

So I have a simple code that seems to take from 4 to 20 seconds to run. I don't know if that is something normal or if I am missing something.
Is this is normal what can I do to improve it, would using BigQuery instead of Sheets help with this kind of variance?
I have already written this in many ways, for, forEach, map. I'm mostly satisfied with the average time, the problem is that it takes too long sometimes like 20 seconds.

Context:
I am developing an Web Application for a client, it fairly simple html for interacting with the sheet. The code runs in the server side.

CODE:

```
function getHomeTableData(req){

  var table = ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getValues().filter(e=>e[1]==sc.decrypt(req.key)) 
  if(table.length==0){return 'true'}

  //sort table by dateIn
  table.sort((a,b)=>a[4]-b[4])

  //formatters
  const dateFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',{timeZone:req.tmz});
  const timeFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { hour: 'numeric',minute:'numeric',timeZone:req.tmz });

  var res = {}
  var status = ''
  const headers = [
            { title: 'TransactionID' },
            { title: 'UserID' },
            { title: 'Location' },
            { title: 'Position' },
            { title: 'Date In' },
            { title: 'Start Time' },
            { title: 'Date Out' },
            { title: 'End Time' },
            { title: 'Shift' }            
        ]

  //Create table data
  for(var i=0;i<table.length;i++){
    const [col1, col2, locationId, role, checkInDate, checkOutDate] = table[i];
    const shiftLengthValue = shiftLength(checkInDate, checkOutDate);
    const dateIn = dateFormatter.format(checkInDate);
    const timeIn = timeFormatter.format(checkInDate);
    const dateOut = checkOutDate ? dateFormatter.format(checkOutDate) : '';
    const timeOut = checkOutDate ? timeFormatter.format(checkOutDate) : '';
    const locationNameValue = locationName(locationId);
    table[i] = [col1, col2, locationNameValue, role, dateIn, timeIn, dateOut, timeOut, shiftLengthValue];
  }

  //sort table by dateIn
  table.sort((a,b)=>a[4]-b[4])

  //return is user still checked in
  if(table[table.length-1][6]==""){
    res = {
      data:table,
      headers:headers,
      checkIn:true,
      dismissModal:false,
      transactionID:table[table.length-1][0],
      checkInDate:"",
      checkInTime:table[table.length-1][5],
      checkInRole:table[table.length-1][3],
      checkInLocation:table[table.length-1][2]
    }
  } else {
    res = {
      data: table,
      headers: headers,
      checkIn: false,
      dismissModal: false,
    }
  }
  return res
}
```

Comment: There are many things in your script that are not included, what is `sc`, `shiftLength`, `locationName`, and why sort `table` twice?